# display latest post with thumbnail wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to display the 3 latest posts of my Wordpress blog using a shortcode. I wrote this php code. It works but display 3 times each posts. Do you know how to fix it please ?

```
$counter = 3;
$recentPosts = new WP_Query();
$recentPosts->query('showposts=3');
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(3);

while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post();

foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
echo '<li class="box'.$counter--.'">';
the_post_thumbnail();
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a>';
echo '</li>';
}

endwhile;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please using wordpress default function `wp_get_recent_posts` use this code

```
<h2>Latest Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 3,
    );

    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args, $output = ARRAY_A);
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"], 'thumbnail' );
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Also adjust your code where you want display.

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code.

```
<?php
 $postslist = get_posts('numberposts=3&order=DESC&orderby=date');
 foreach ($postslist as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post);
 ?>
 <div class="entry">
 <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
 <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')) ?>
 <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
 </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code.

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
```